# node request post data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying to post some JSON data to a RESTful API. But  data is not posted. I used node request from : https://github.com/request/request
and used code snippets from that page.
my code snippet :

```
var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: 'http://abcd.dfgh.com/v2.0/observations',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'x-api-key': '123456=',
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
};

SensorTag.discover(function(sensorTag) {
    function callback(error, response, postdata) {
        console.log("HERE GOES POST DATA : " + postdata);
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var info = JSON.parse(postdata);
            console.log(info.stargazers_count + " Stars");
            console.log(info.forks_count + " Forks");
        }
    }
    async.series([
        /*some functions*/
        function(callback) {
            setTimeout(callback, 2000);
            loop();
        }
    ])
    function loop() {
        async.series([
            /*Some functions*/
            function(callback) {
                /*data etc...*/
                var postdata = "{ \"version\": \"1.0.1\", \"observations\": [ { \"sensor\": \"TISensorTag_temp_01\", \"record\": [ { \"starttime\": \"" + formatDate(new Date()) + "\", \"output\": [ { \"name\": \"ObjTemp\", \"value\": \"" + objtemp + "\" }, { \"name\": \"AmbTemp\", \"value\": \"" + ambtemp + "\" } ] } ] } ] }";
                request.post(options, callback);
            }

        ])
    }
})
```

But data is not posted, it keeps on looping without posting data. Can anyone please clarify what happened ?
Also what I found is the `request` is not calling `callback function` because this part I can't see :

```
console.log("HERE GOES POST DATA : "+postdata);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like you actually use `postdata`

Comment: @ExplosionPills please check the callback function

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually using your `postdata` variable.

Try piping it to the request, e.g.

```
var req = request.pos(options, callback);
req.end(postdata); // Writes data to the stream, and closes it
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `postdata` while sending request:

```
var postdata = "{ \"version\": \"1.0.1\", \"observations\": [ { \"sensor\": \"TISensorTag_temp_01\", \"record\": [ { \"starttime\": \"" + formatDate(new Date()) + "\", \"output\": [ { \"name\": \"ObjTemp\", \"value\": \"" + objtemp + "\" }, { \"name\": \"AmbTemp\", \"value\": \"" + ambtemp + "\" } ] } ] } ] }";
options.data = postdata; //added data to post request
request.post(options, callback);
```

---

About **Callback**, you have initialized callback and in your case you don't have to pass callback as function parameter. Try use following:

```
async.series([
    /*some functions*/
    function() {
        setTimeout(callback, 2000);
        loop();
    }
])
```

Comment: and I have to set another callback for the POST response that's why I set it

Comment: I tried with this : http://blog.modulus.io/node.js-tutorial-how-to-use-request-module 
It worked but this is not optimized code, for many functions I need to write many times. while this would optimize. Please let me know how to do this